# Find the correct options

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $$S_n=\sum_{r=1}^nt_r$$ where $t_1=1$ and $t_r\ge0$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$. If $$S_n=\frac{1}{2}\left(t_n+\frac{1}{t_n}\right)$$ then (Where $[\cdot]$ denotes the greatest integer function).

$1.$ $S_{100}=10$

$2.$ $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(S_nt_n)=\frac{1}{2}$

$3.$ $\displaystyle\left[\sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac{1}{S_n}\right]=18$

$4.$ $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(S_nt_n)=1$

---

I tired by multiplying $S_n$ by $t_n$ but then got stuck. Also we don't have any way to generate more $t_i$, so how can we find the sum of the series till $100$$?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solving for $S_n,t_n$

Since $S_n=\sum_{r=1}^n t_r$, we can infer that $S_n-S_{n-1}=t_n$. Therefore, we are left with two equations
$$\begin{cases}
S_n-S_{n-1}=t_n\\S_n=\frac12\left(t_n+\frac1{t_n}\right)
\end{cases}$$
which we can use to eliminate $t_n$ and obtain an equation relating $S_n$ and $S_{n-1}$:
$$\begin{aligned}
&S_n=\frac12\left(S_n-S_{n-1}+\frac1{S_n-S_{n-1}}\right)\\
&\implies S_n+S_{n-1}=\frac1{S_n-S_{n-1}}\\
&\implies1=\left(S_n+S_{n-1}\right)\left(S_n-S_{n-1}\right)=S_n^2-S_{n-1}^2
\end{aligned}$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{aligned}
S_n^2=1+S_{n-1}^2=1+(1+S_{n-2}^2)=...=n-1+S^2_1=n
\end{aligned}$$
which means $S_n=+\sqrt{n}$ (since $t_r\ge0$) and $t_n=\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}$.

#### Going through the options

We can now compute the quantities mentioned in the options. Here are some possible approaches:
For option 1, direct substitution gives $S_{100}=\sqrt{100}=10$.
For options 2 and 4, we can express $S_nt_n$ as
$$\begin{aligned}
S_nt_n&=\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}\right)=n\left(1-\sqrt{1-\frac1n}\right)\end{aligned}$$
and use L'Hôpital's rule as follows:
$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{n\to\infty}S_nt_n&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\frac1n}}{1/n}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-\frac12(1-1/n)^{-1/2}\cdot(1/n^2)}{-1/n^2}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac12(1-1/n)^{-1/2}\\&=\frac12
\end{aligned}$$
Finally, for option 3, direct computation gives $\lfloor\sum_{n=1}^{100}S_n\rfloor=\lfloor\sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac1{\sqrt n}\rfloor=\lfloor18.5896...\rfloor=18$. You can also deduce this fact without direct computation in multiple ways. For instance, summing the elementary bound
$$
\frac1{2\sqrt{n}}>\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$$
from $n=1$ to $100$ gives
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}>2\left(\sqrt{101}-1\right)>2(\sqrt{100}-1)=18
$$
while the integral-based bound
$$\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac1{\sqrt3}+...+\frac1{\sqrt N}<\int_1^N\frac{\text{d}x}{\sqrt{x}}=2\sqrt{N}-2$$
which can be deduced by drawing rectangles below the graph of $y=1/\sqrt{x}$, implying that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}<2\sqrt{100}-2+1=19$$
Together, these bounds imply $18<\sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}<19\implies\lfloor\sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac1{\sqrt n}\rfloor=18$.

Therefore, options 1,2 and 3 are correct.